# How to dynamically choose which element to render in ReactJS

Tags: html, reactjs

I am writing a webpage which dynamically renders elements from a database, with each one having its own state. To choose what element is rendered, I used a `switch-case` like this:

```
switch (this.state.type) {
  case 'textarea':
    element = <textarea {...this.state} />
    break

  ...

  default:
    element = <input {...this.state} />
}
```

What I would like to do is have a nice way of choosing which element is rendered, like this:

```
switch (this.state.type) {
  case 'textarea':
    tag = 'textarea'
    break

  ...

  default:
    tag = 'input'
}

element = <{tag} {...this.state} />
```

Is there a way to something similar to this in React?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `React.createElement` [1], whose first argument is the element to render.

[1] https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement

Comment: While this is true, I'd recommend against it. The doc you linked to says `You will not typically invoke React.createElement() directly if you are using JSX` So make sure you really need it before going crazy with it

Answer (score 1):

You can already do that, the variable should start with an uppercase:

```
function getElementTag(type) {
  switch (type) {
    case 'textarea':
      return 'textarea'
    default:
      return 'input'
  }
}

function App() {
  const TagName = getElementTag('textarea');
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TagName value="you can already do it" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: That is very cool. Thank you!
But, why should the variable start with an uppercase? Is it just convention-wise?

Comment: It is a JSX convention so that it can differentiate between native HTML elements (lowercase) and React Components (capitalize) otherwise it will try and render a html tag called `tagName` straight into the browser.